# bash: Check if a file in sequence is missing

Tags: bash, file

I have a bunch of files in a directory whose names contain numbers.

```
/mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0/S0Test_26060_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
/mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0/S0Run_26061_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
/mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0/S0Test_26063_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
/mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0/S0Run_26065_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
```

What I'd like to do is find which files are missing and then do something with those. In the above case the files which contains numbers `26062`, `26064` are missing.

So far I'm doing the following

```
#___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
#-3-Find the missing runs
    REPLAYED_RUNS_DIR=/ /mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0
    echo "..........Looking for non replayed runs in the range $smallest_run-$biggest_run"
    for (( i=$smallest_run; i<=$biggest_run; ++i));do
        filename="$REPLAYED_DATA_DIR/*$i*.root"
        #echo $filename
        if [ ! -f $filename ]; then
             echo "Run $i does not exist."
             ./produce_file $i
        fi
    done
```

This snippet manages to find files that are missing, however I have a few issues:

1. In some cases I get the following error for files that do exist and I have no idea why.

`./check_missing.sh: line 53: [: /mnt/exp-data/6/instrument/caen2018/stage0/S0Run_25829_500ns_CW_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root: binary operator expected`

2. If I uncomment `echo filename` the I get as an output the full name and directory of the files, as if I was doing `ls instead of` echo`. Is this to be expected?
3. Is there a better way (i,e, faster, more efficient) to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I assume your filenames are always `text_X_wha_te_ver` and you want X to be tested, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script to do this in a more massive way.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
d="path/to/directory"
start=$1
end=$2

join -v1 <(
    seq "$start" "$end"
) <(
    find "$d" -type f -printf "%f\0" |
    awk -F"/" -v RS="\0" '{split($NF,a,"_"); print a[2]}' | sort
) | xargs -r -n1 echo ./produce_file
```

`join -v1 file1 file2` will output all lines of `file1` not in `file2`. In place of those two files, using process substitution, we put the sequence to be tested, and the filenames by `find`, filtered by `awk` to get the number in them and finally sorted, because `join` wants sorted inputs.

Finally you can pipe the result to your script `produce_file`. `-r` stands for `--no-run-if-empty` which is a GNU extension to avoid one execution with empty input if the previous command gave no arguments.

Remove `echo` after testing. If your script can process multiple number arguments, remove `-n1` also, to process all of them at once.

---

Testing:

```sh
> mkdir -p path/to/directory
touch path/to/directory/S0Test_26060_0ns_CBT_0ns_DEBT.root
touch path/to/directory/S0Run_26061_500ns.root
touch path/to/directory/S0Test_26063_500ns_CW.root
touch path/to/directory/S0Test_26065_500ns.root
touch path/to/directory/S0Test_30000_500ns.root
> bash test.sh 26060 26065
./produce_file 26062
./produce_file 26064
```

Comment: Remember to run it with `bash test.sh` or any other way you run bash scripts and not `sh` in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The files are not ascii files. I think that's the reason that I get a list all "number" in the directory when I run your script using `echo`. Of course I might be missing something

Comment: I don't understand what you get. Can you give an example? Also we only test filenames, we don't test the files in general.

Comment: I get `./produce_file #####` where `#####` corresponds to each number from `$start` to `$end` (I'm using the notation on your script. So it's like doing `for (i=$start; i<=$end; ++i);do echo ./produce_file $i; done`

Comment: Probably you have more underscores in the paths, currently I match the number betwwen the first and second `_`. Update with more representative filenames, so we find a better description of what to match.

Comment: You are correct!! I'll update my question shortly. But I don't necessarily know the number of underscores beforehand.

Comment: I now understand what you are trying to do and `awk -F_ '{print $2}'` should work :/

Comment: Yes, I updated with FS as / so we keep only the filename, and split by `_` and print 2nd field. Ensure the number is always at that field or it's nor hard to find any other matching pattern yourself for awk I think.

Comment: It does the trick! Thanks a lot! It's a very smart way to use `join`!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it using `find` and `[ -z "$filename"]` to check if `find` returned an empty entry.

```
for (( i=$start; i<=$endn; ++i ));do
    filename=`find "$DIR" -type f -name "*$i*"`
    if [ -z "$filename" ]; then
        echo "File $i does not exist."
    fi
done
```